# How do I replace part of string with various combinations in lookup in Python?

Tags: python, string, lookup, python-itertools

I have the following code replacing every element with it's short form in the lookup:

```
case = ["MY_FIRST_RODEO"]
lookup = {'MY': 'M', 'FIRST': 'FRST', 'RODEO' : 'RD', 'FIRST_RODEO': 'FRD', 'MY_FIRST': 'MF', 'MY_FIRST_RODEO': 'MFR'}
case_mod = []
for string in case:
    words = string.split("_")
    new_string = [lookup[word] for word in words]
    case_mod.append("_".join(new_string))
print(case_mod)
```

This returns:

```
['M_FRST_RD']
```

However, I want it to additionally return all possibilities since in the lookup, I have short words for all MY_FIRST, FIRST_RODEO, and MY_FIRST_RODEO. So, I want the following returned:

```
['M_FRST_RD', 'MF_RD', 'M_FRD', 'MFR']
```

I was able to write code to break the original list into all possibilities as follows:

```
case = ["MY_FIRST_RODEO"]
result = []
for string in case:
    words = string.split("_")
    n = len(words)
    for i in range(n):
        result.append("_".join(words[:i + 1]))
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            result.append("_".join(words[i:j + 1]))
            result.extend(words)
result = list(dict.fromkeys(result))
print(result)
```

to return:

```
['MY', 'MY_FIRST', 'FIRST', 'RODEO', 'MY_FIRST_RODEO', 'FIRST_RODEO']
```

But somehow can't make the connection between the two solutions. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: make all posibility of split, and then run code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try is the following:

```py
from itertools import combinations

string = "MY_FIRST_RODEO"
lookup = {'MY': 'M', 'FIRST': 'FRST', 'RODEO' : 'RD', 'FIRST_RODEO': 'FRD', 'MY_FIRST': 'MF', 'MY_FIRST_RODEO': 'MFR'}

underscores = [i for i, c in enumerate(string) if c == "_"]
length = len(string)
results = []
for r in range(len(underscores), -1, -1):
    for parts in combinations(underscores, r):
        limits = ((a + 1, b) for a, b in zip((-1,) + parts, parts + (length,)))
        results.append("_".join(lookup[string[a:b]] for a, b in limits))
```

First record the indices of `string` with an underscore and then use them  with [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) (from the standard library module `itertools`) to choose all the different partitions of `string` along the underscores. (I've left out the outer loop over `case` since that is not needed to show the proposed mechanic.)

Result here:

```
['M_FRST_RD', 'M_FRD', 'MF_RD', 'MFR']
```

Comment: Wow wasn't aware of combinations method under itertools. Seems very powerful. Out the bat, how do I make this more robust if say lookup doesn't have the  key value pair 'MY_FIRST_RODEO': 'MFR', then rather than throwing a Key Error, it just doesn't try to find it giving the result: ['M_FRST_RD', 'M_FRD', 'MF_RD']

Comment: Solved: Just changed the way dictionary is searched. Return same string if key isnt found in dictionary.
```results.append("_".join(lookup.get(string[a:b],string[a:b]) for a, b in limits))```